# Is it legal to "sneak into Mar-a-Lago"?

Tags: united-states, florida, is-x-legal, trespassing

[This article](https://airmail.news/issues/2021-3-13/how-to-sneak-into-mar-a-lago) lists six ways to "sneak into Mar-a-Lago." It says "it’s not illegal to go places you don’t belong," but most of the ways listed seem like fraud and/or trespassing. Is it really legal to "sneak into Mar-a-Lago?

Comment: It all depends on your purpose. If you booked a hotel room, went for a drink with your mates and sneak in at 3am without waking up your wife, likely fine.

Comment: The linked article is behind a subscription wall. Do you have anything else?

Comment: "it’s not illegal to go places you don’t belong": sometimes.  Frequently, however, it very much is illegal to go places you don't belong.

Comment: @Rick I just used Guerilla Mail to create a temporary address to enter: https://www.guerrillamail.com/. Just copy the email address that that gives you and paste it into the article's subscription wall. It should unlock the article in a few seconds (you will get a subscription email but can ignore it), and the site never gets your real email (just a temporary webmail address).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Florida trespass law is [here](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0800-0899/0810/Sections/0810.08.html). It is a crime if one "without being authorized, licensed, or invited, willfully enters or remains in any structure or conveyance" (also, the refuse to depart when told to by an authorized person). Additionally, "entry by any person into or upon any enclosed and posted land" is deemed to be prima facie evidence of an intent to trespass ("posted land" refers to those warning signs). "Posting" has certain formal requirements.

It is beyond the scope of a Law SE question to determine whether it is legally possible to enter the grounds of Mar-a-lago in light of presence of absence of no-trespassing signs.